# Seekable of Flv with ExoPlayer

Tags: flv, exoplayer2.x

When I use Exoplayer to play flv video, in default , I can't seek the progress.

Look at **FlvExtractor.java**:

```
  @Override
  public boolean isSeekable() {
    return false;
  }
```

Change this method and return `true`, then I can seek the progress.

Why Google make it unseekable in default?